# Como unir en dos room al mismo usuario con socket.io?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vuex

Estoy trabajando con socket.io y me gustaria poder enviar un mensaje a cierto grupo de usuarios. se que puedo lograr esto usando las room, pero me surge un problema cuando quiero que un usuario pertenesca a dos room simultaneamente.

por ejemplo, para que pertenesca al chat `global` y un grupo especifico por ejemplo `grupo-amigos`.

Quiero que pueda recibir mensajes de ambos grupos.
pero cuando unó al socket a una segunda room deja de recibir mensajes de la primera.

Estoy usando Vue.

`chat.vue`

```
 methods: {
    pushMessage(msg) {
      let chat = document.querySelector(".list-msg");
      this.listMsg.push(msg);
      chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight + "px";
    },
    sendMessage(message) {
      this.socket.emit("chat:message", {
        text: message,
        username: this.store.state.DATA_USER.username,
        room: this.dataConnect.room,
      });
    },
    getMessages() {
      this.socket.on("chat:message", (data) => {
        this.pushMessage({
          username: data.username,
          text: data.text,
          color: "black",
        });
      });
    },
    clearChat() {
      this.listMsg = [];
    },
    sendToServer() {
      if (this.writingChat.length > 0) {
        this.sendMessage(this.writingChat);
        this.writingChat = "";
      }
    },
  },
  components: {
    SendCircle,
    Earth,
    SendOutline,
  },

  computed: {
    dataConnect() {
      this.clearChat();
      return {
        username: this.store.state.DATA_USER?.username,
        room: this.store.state.ROOM,
      };
    },
  },
  watch: {
    dataConnect() {
      if (this.dataConnect.username && this.dataConnect.room) {
        console.log(this.dataConnect);
        this.socket.emit("join:room", {
          username: this.dataConnect.username,
          room: this.dataConnect.room,
          id: socket.id,
        });
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getMessages();
  },
```

Lo que hago aqui es observar cuando estan cargados los datos de la room y el usuario para enviar al servidor el evento `join:room`

`server.js`

```
class ConnectSockets {
 constructor(server) {
   const socketio = require("socket.io");
   this.io = socketio(server);
   this.connection();
 }
 connection() {
   this.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
     console.log(`user connect`);
     this.disconnect(socket);
     this.chatMessage(socket);
     this.joinRom(socket);
   });
 }
 joinRom(socket) {
   socket.on("join:room", (data) => {
     console.log(data.username + " se unio a '" + data.room.title + "'");
     socket.join(data.room.title);
   });
 }
 disconnect(socket) {
   socket.on("disconnect", () => {
     console.log(`user disconnected`);
   });
 }
 chatMessage(socket) {
   socket.on("chat:message", (data) => {
     this.io.to(data.room.title).emit("chat:message", data);
   });
 }
}
```

Y esta es una clase que utilizo para manejar los socket del lado del servidor.

Comment: No creo que se pueda con rooms. Intenta con namespaces. https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/